# Additional "12" in printf output in C

Tags: c, string, null, character

I wrote the following program to learn how `\0` character works in C programs:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    char a[] = {'1','2','\0','2'};
    int i=0;
    for (i=0; i<4; i++){
        printf("%c\n",a[i]);
    }
    printf("%s",a);
    return 0;
}
```

Well, that's okay and I have the following output :

```
sh-4.3$ gcc -o main *.c                                                                                          
sh-4.3$ main                                                                                                     
1                                                                                                                
2                                                                                                                

2
```

But when I remove `\n` character from `printf` command, I receive one additional `12` in output:

```
//. Same as above
    for (i=0; i<4; i++){
        printf("%c",a[i]);
    }
//. Same as above
```

Output is:

```
12sh-4.3$ gcc -o main *.c                                                                                        
sh-4.3$ main 
12212
```

While I think I must see this :

```
12sh-4.3$ gcc -o main *.c                                                                                        
sh-4.3$ main 
122
```

*Note that I used [this online compiler](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_c_online.php) to compile above programs. It's GNU GCC v4.8.3*

Comment: are you sure that is the o/p you're getting?

Comment: Are you sure it's `12122`, not `12212`?

Comment: [can't reproduce](http://ideone.com/LwIqHc)

Comment: @SouravGhosh What is `o/p` means?

Comment: o/p --> output...sorry for any confusion, :-)

Comment: The 1st output  you show seems incomplete.

Comment: Add a final `printf("\n");` to both examples and get enlightend.

Comment: You are aware there are **two**  `printf()`s in the code you show, aren't you?

Comment: @alk OMG!! you are right!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The extra `12` you are getting is from the `printf("%s",a);` line:

- Iterating through the loop prints out the characters `1`, `2`, null (nothing), and `2`.
- Printing out the string at `a` prints up until the null character (`\0`), so `12`.

That's why you get the output `12212`.

---

Printing with the newlines prints out `1`, `2`, new line, `2`, and `12` on separate lines.

In your example you are missing the final `12` because you don't have new line at the end so your shell prompt gets printed after it: notice in your question that you have `12sh-4.3$` at the beginning of one of the lines.